# PHP SoapClient creating error: "Namespace must not match the enclosing schema"

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm getting "Namespace must not match the enclosing schema" error when trying to create SoapClient object. Code is simple:

```
<?php $client = new \SoapClient('http://www.server.com/Service?wsdl');
```

How can I create object by ignoring this error?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the WSDL looks like, so it's a bit hard to tell if the error can be avoided. However, you can switch to creating a `SoapClient` using non WSDL mode:

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://localhost/soap.php",
                                 'uri'      => "http://test-uri/"));
```

Where `location` and `uri` are described as:

> An array of options. If working in
>   WSDL mode, this parameter is optional.
>   If working in non-WSDL mode, the
>   location and uri options must be set,
>   where location is the URL to request
>   and uri is the target namespace of the
>   SOAP service.

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php